# setup nginx to use another gateway in case of 504 error

Tags: node.js, nginx

I got the following `nginx` config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainName.com;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/logName.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location ~ ^/(min/|images/|ckeditor/|img/|javascripts/|apple-touch-icon-ipad.png|apple-touch-icon-ipad3.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone4.png|generated/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
          root /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeJsProject/port/public; 
          access_log off;
          expires max;
        }
}
```

It is proxy for `node.js` application on port `9000`.

**Is it possible** to change this config to let `nginx` use another proxy url (on port `9001` for example) in case `nginx` got `504` error.

I need this in case when node.js server is down on port `9000` and need several seconds to restart automatically and several seconds `nginx` gives `504` error for every request. I want `nginx` to "guess" that `node.js` site on port `9000` is down and use reserve node.js site on port `9001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) module.

```
upstream node {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server 127.0.0.1:9001 backup;
}

server {
...
    proxy_pass http://node/;
...
}
```